# Using height 100% on a floated child <div>

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with two divs inside.
The first div will be positioned on the left with one a picture height of 100% and the other is next to it (on the right) with the content.

I'm not able to make the left div follow the parent div. 
The height 100% not work.

See photo in what is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCdmJ.jpg

The result was to be this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHLFD.jpg

Below is my code in jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AHd65/

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="enquetes-listagem">
    <div class="enquete">
        <div class="enquete-foto">
            <a href=""><img src="http://img7.orkut.com/images/tiny/1324184718/564030436/ip.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="enquete-data">
            <a href="" class="afb">Juninho CHR</a>
            <span class="grb">
                <span id="gwt-uid-604">241 votos.</span>
                <span class="" id="gwt-uid-605" title="19/10/2011 18:18:34">19/10/2011</span>
            </span>
            <div class="o-b">
                <a href="#CommPoll?cmm=111812829&amp;pid=1928547172&amp;pct=1319030314">Que tipo de computador você prefere?</a>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="">
                        Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* div pai */
.enquetes-listagem .enquete {
    background: yellow;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/* div filho esquerda */
.enquetes-listagem .enquete .enquete-foto {
    max-width: 34px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 100%; /* Not Work, why???? */
    background: red;
}

/* div filho direita */
.enquetes-listagem .enquete .enquete-data {
    background: blue;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try floating both your .enquete-foto and .enquete-data left and setting the parent divs background blue, like so:

```
.enquete-foto, enquete-data {
  float:left;
  display:block;
}

.enquete-foto img {
  height: 100%
}

.enquetes-listagem .enquete {
   background: blue;
   display:block;
   min-height: 70px; #This could be any height?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code : [CheckItOut](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/AHd65/24/)

css:

---

```
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

 .enquetes-listagem .enquete {
    background: yellow;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position:relative;
    height:60px;
}

 .enquetes-listagem .enquete .enquete-foto {
    position:absolute;
    max-width: 34px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background: red;
    height:inherit;
}

 .enquetes-listagem .enquete .enquete-data {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 34px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    height:inherit;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, have you looked at your own fiddle?

Comment: now check and ask questions! i ve given parent div some height! and child dive will inherit their parent divs height! like a magic

Comment: I don't think that's what OP wants, based on the image he's added: http://i.imgur.com/nuQ5Rnj.jpg

Comment: Now another div does not follow when trying to add more content -> http://jsfiddle.net/AHd65/28/

Comment: just increase the size of parent or set it auto

Comment: if the no of div is not countable or dynamic then set parent height:auto;

Comment: it will automatically increases height

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using tables: http://jsfiddle.net/AHd65/30/.

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #428bca;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* div pai */
.enquetes-listagem .enquete {
    background: yellow;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.enquetes-listagem .enquete .enquete-foto {
    width: 34px;
    background: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.enquetes-listagem .enquete .enquete-data {
    background: blue;
    display: table-cell;
}
```